# How to add a time limit for user to input something or else it goes on?

Tags: c++

Since very long time, I am trying to put a timer in C++ which actually gives a limited time to input anything like for example :-
if I type

```
cout<<"Enter the name :-  
cin>>name;  
cout<<"Enter Phonenoe :- ";  
cin>>phoneno;
```

So in this How can I add time say for 5 secs to input name, and if user don't input anything in 5 secs, programs should go to input phonenoe.

Give the full code, I am a beginner.

Comment: This was asked already a day or two ago.  It received limited answers then with someone actually attempting to code it.  A Gimme teh c0dz question won't do much better.

Comment: It doesn't work out well in standard C++. You could give the impression that it does if there's nothing happening after, but in reality, it doesn't.

Comment: Downvote for no attempt to solve the problem and request for 'the full code'

Comment: I'm not going to "Give the full code" but an answer lies in threads. Start a timer, spawn a thread that takes the user input, if exceeds time, kill the thread and set value to default.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk, Except you'll have to use a non-standard method to kill it.

Comment: @chris: Very true. I can't think of a way to do this in a portable manner.

Answer (score 1):

Fine, I am overruled.

The best google I found for this is [here](http://www.coldestgame.com/site/blog/cybertron/non-blocking-reading-stdin-c).  In a nutshell, this is very difficult to do in C++ and I believe impossible to do in a portable way.  In assembler, I would poll the lowest level keyboard interrupt (9h I think) to see what is coming in, but that was in DOS days and I'm not sure if that works anymore.

Answer (score 1):

just for fun. only works in windows.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool wait_for_key(int timeout_milliseconds, char& ch) {
    HANDLE tui_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    DWORD tui_evtc = 0;
    DWORD deadline = GetTickCount() + timeout_milliseconds;
    INPUT_RECORD tui_inrec = { 0 };
    DWORD tui_numread = 0;

    while (GetTickCount() < deadline) {
        if (tui_evtc > 0) {
            ReadConsoleInput(tui_handle, &tui_inrec, 1, &tui_numread);
            if (tui_inrec.EventType == KEY_EVENT) {
                if (tui_inrec.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) {
                    ch = tui_inrec.Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        YieldProcessor();
        GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents(tui_handle, &tui_evtc);
    }

    return false;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE tui_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    std::string name;
    std::string other;

    std::cout << "name: ";

    char ch;
    if (wait_for_key(5000, ch)) {
        std::cout << ch;
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        name = ch + name;

        std::cout << "name is '" << name.c_str() << "'" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << std::endl << "other: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, other);

        std::cout << "other is '" << other.c_str() << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```